# Fetching data from array and dynamic route display in nextjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, fetch, next.js

I am learning Nextjs framework and I am having difficulty with dynamic route and how to fetch the data from an array. I followed the basics of Nextjs but this got me stuck.

What I want?

Get the information of this array which is stored as a items.tsx file:

```
export const projects = [
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Italian recipes book',
    description: `This a web design and soon-to-be a fully functional and responsive React application` 
 },
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Chat App website',
    description: `This is a homepage design and build for a concept project – a chat application. I designed the page
    first then built a responsive web page using Webflow.`
  },
]
```

As per nextjs website I was able to fetch the id and created a function to get the project data like so

```
import { projects } from "../models/projects";

export function getAllItemsIds() {
  return projects.map(project => {
    return {
      params: {
        id: project.id,
      }
    }
  })
}

export function getProjectData(id) {
  return {
    id,
  }
}
```

I believe the function getProjectData(id) is missing the rest of the data and I'm having problems on how to fetch it. I want to show the info of the array in my [id].tsx file according to the parameter (in this case, to the ID 1 or 2).
This is my [id].tsx file:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = getAllItemsIds()
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const projectData = getProjectData(params.id)
  return {
    props: {
      projectData
    }
  }
}



const Project = ({ projectData }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
       {projectData.id}
       {projectData.title}
       {projectData.description}  
      </div>
      
      </>
  )
}

export default Project;
```

As of now I am only able to display my projectData.id and I got a bit confused with all the getStaticPaths() and getStaticProps() thing. I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's the right way to do it, but I managed to do what I wanted like so:

added the other parameters and mapped the array inside the getProjectData

```
export function getProjectData(id, title, description ) {
  projects.map(data => {
    if (data.id === id) {
      title = data.title;
      description = data.description;
    }
  });
  return {
    id,
    title,
    description
  }
}
```

and in the [id].tsx I updates the getStaticProps like so

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params, title, description }) {
  const projectData = getProjectData(params.id, title, description)
  return {
    props: {
      projectData
    }
  }
}
```

It did fetch the data according to the id parameter!